# React-leaflet not rendering map properly in Ionic

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, leaflet, react-leaflet

[image]

I've seen several people having this problem, however non of the solutions presented helped me. I believe I setup everything correctly.

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ionic App</title>

    <base href="/" />

    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/icon/favicon.png" />

    <!-- Leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin="" />

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>

    <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Ionic App" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Just in case imported this in index.js

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
```

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

import './Tab1.css';

const Tab1 = () => {
    const data = {
        lat: 51.505,
        lng: -0.09,
        zoom: 5
    }

    const position = [data.lat, data.lng];
    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>Tab 1</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent fullscreen>
                <Map center={position} zoom={data.zoom} style={{ height: "100vh" }} >
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    <Marker position={position}>
                        <Popup>
                            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                </Map>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    );
};

export default Tab1;
```

Finally in Tab1.css:

```
.leaflet-container{
    height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

End effect is that the only tile that loads on load is topleft one and then when i scroll it loads random tiles. Am I really missing something?

Comment: Dont know if that helps anything, but just realised if I open or close devtools it starts to work. Doesnt make any sense to me

Answer (score 1):

try this, we are invalidating the map to get it to re-render

```html
<TileLayer 
   onLoad={(e:any)=> { e.target._map.invalidateSize()}}
   attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
   url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
```

source - https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/46

Comment: Worked for Firefox, didnt work for Chrome, it still loads incomplete BUT loads completely when i move the map a bit.
Are you familiar with Leaflet? Because I'm making an app that relies a lot on maps and when just displaying a map needs workarounds im scared I will run into obstacles all the time, does it have a lot of issues?

Comment: you can also add wrap it in a `setTimeout` and that should work. I tested this on chrome so I am surprised it didn't work for you.

Comment: @AaronSaunders For now I made a workaround, when component mounts I just do a setTimeout for 1S, and set latitude to some far away place and then immediately set it back to proper latitude, this forces refresh of the tiles. Also tasted on other machine and a phone, same issue when Chrome is used. Even Edge had no issues with just your solution. I'll play with this library some more, because I don't really have alternatives.

Comment: @MazMat curious to see your code, i had none of this issues you mentioned